# Datos en datagridview se superponen

Tags: c#, datagrid

como andan? Tengo un datagridview y los datos se me superponen. Les muestro como queda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se debe? Ademas tambien cuando me posiciono sobre por ejemplo el boton elegir, me permite cambiarle el tamano en tiempo de ejecucion, como prohibo que no se pueda cambiar el tamano de las filas/columnas?

Comment: que eventos defines en el datagridview? quizas alguno que aplique merge de celdas. Esta muy raro el diseño del grid, generalmente no luce de esa forma.

Comment: El datagridview se ve bien cuando busco, el problema es cuando bajo la barra de scroll. Ahi las filas que no se veian al principio, se superponen con las de arriba cuando vuelvo a subir. En los eventos solo tengo el cellcontent click que me seleccione la que hizo click en elegir. Nada mas.

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir lo que dice @LeandroTuttini.. Ese grid luce raro. Es el grid comun de .net? o es un control de usuario particular? esos botones no son comunes en un grid.

Comment: de casualidad extendieron el datagridview en algun componente heredado, porque ese scroll tampoco es el normal del grid, la verdad es que no se como ayudar si analizar el codigo. Se me ocurre que podrias poner otros grid, arrastandolo directo desde la toolbox, le asignas los datos y valida como se visualiza, solo eso simple, no le definas ningun evento, para ver el aspecto y poder comparar

Comment: Borre ese grid y puse otro desde la barra de herramientas y funciona sin problemas! No se que habre tocado en el diseno que hacia eso! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hice un datagrid con transparencia y la imagen que se puso como fondo era muy pesada, y ocurría el buck que se muestra en la imagen del compañero; lo que hice fue disminuir el peso de la imagen hasta maso menos 40kb y ya no ocurre ese problema. Por si a alguien le sirve.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).